# Statically linking against non-pic 3rd party library

Tags: ios, iphone

I am building an iPhone application that I need to be position-independent.  I am linking against third-party libraries to which I do not have source code.

1. If such a library has not been compiled with -fPIC and therefore is not position-independent, can I still link against it to produce a valid PIE binary?
2. Will the dynamic loader handle any text relocations that occur due to code from this library.
3. If not, what are my possible options to resolve this situation and still produce a PIE binary?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, whether a source file was built with `-fPIC` or not, is not important unless you plan to create a dynamic library out of its object file. Actually most static libraries aren't built in a position independent manner. Not that that this would be forbidden, but it will result in a slightly bigger and slower binary later on (as the compiler/linker will not be able to perform certain types of optimizations).

And a binary runs in an address space of its own, it doesn't have to be position independent at all. That's the reason why dynamic libraries must be position independent as they are shared among different binaries that all require different memory positions for themselves, so it must be possible for the dynamic linker to move the library elsewhere in the process space of a binary at runtime.

Or to say it in even simpler words: Just link against that static library and everything will be fine.